# internal audio record using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, web-audio-api

I have a website that merges songs together and adding some effects to them...

after I finish the process of editing the sounds I need to record the new one but I need to *record it* **internally not through the microphone** since it will cause some noise and the sound will not be perfect.

note: the website is programmed using javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "record internally" ? If you don't want to record it through the microphone, why don't you just load the file using a file input ?

Comment: since in my website I load the song then I do some effects to it like equalizer and some filters so and i need to record the result

Comment: But what do you need to record from, then ? Is the script outputing the song through the speakers ?

Comment: yes it outputs through the speaker, I try to record the sound from the microphone he loses the quality and contains noise

Comment: Then you should record (and maybe output to) another device. Look around "Stereo Mix" or custom drivers like "Virtual Audio Cable"